# Facebook Android Integration: Should not pass a read permission error

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, authorization

I am developing an android app, where the user should be able to log in with a Facebook account. The application has worked in the first 5-10 min. I could see the layout where i was prompted to give/deny permissions.

When i try to log in, it shows me the `"Loading"` message from Facebook API but then returns to the previous layout.

The error message i receive is: `"Should not pass a read () permission to a request for publish or manage authorization"`.

I appreciate any help to resolve this issue..

```
package com.kampusbilisim.sencebence;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.json.*;

import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG = "SenceBence";

    private static String APP_ID = "659712077445489";
    private Facebook facebook;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    Button btnFbLogin;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginToFacebook();
                Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, "Logging in.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.girisyazisibeyaz);
        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Bold.otf"));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email" , "publish_actions", "publish_checkins", "publish_stream" },  
                    new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error
                }
                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove this "publish_stream" permission from authorize.

Comment: i have removed that "publish_stream" but nothing changed. I still can not get the access_token as output, or log in. I have cleaned my code, so its now much easier to read.

Comment: You still have other `publish_*` permissions in there. You should not ask for read and write permissions at the same time. Asking for write permissions should only occur when they are needed for the first time.